# Python save xlPicture from clipboard

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, win32com

Currently I have an xlPicture saved in my clipboard from the call (via win32com):

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(8+rows,total_length)).CopyPicture() #Copies xlPicture to clipboard
```

Now I want to save the image in my clipboard to a file, so I tried using PIL:

```
    from PIL import ImageGrab
    img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
    img.save(os.path.join(r'C:\Windows\Temp\WS_Template_Images','test.png'),'PNG')
```

But `ImageGrab.grabclipboard()` returns None, I assume xlPicture is somehow not a compatible type for the call. Is there anything I can change to use ImageGrab or is there an alternate solution completely to saving an xlPicture? Thanks!

Comment: Is this because `xlPicture` is vector graphics file format but `PIL` doesn't support vector graphics? If you're saving to `png` anyway, couldn't you use `CopyPicture(Format = 2)` to copy in raster graphics from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Turns out I can achieve this with the simple work around of :

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(8+rows,total_length)).CopyPicture()    
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.ActiveSheet
ws.Paste()
ws.Shapes('Picture 1').Copy()
img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
imgFile = os.path.join(r'C:\Windows\Temp\WS_Template_Images','test.png')
img.save(imgFile)
```

Pasting the image in a new workbook and then recopying and saving works, because this way the cell data is unlinked and it is considered an Image which ImageGrab can now get.

Comment: One caveat: Excel will not copy large images to the system clipboard. They will appear on the Office clipboard, but you will be unable to use ImageGrab.grabclipboard() for them.